# Search as you type - highlight matches

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am using the following function to filter elements and only display the ones containing the string - sort of search as you type.

```js
var filter = $(this).val();
var count = 0;    
$(SearchableElements).each(function() {
    if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
        // hide
    } else {
        // show matches
        count++;
    }
});​
```

**[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/Seefeld/3JuJz/9/)**

Can you think of any way of highlighting matches in the text? Any `wrap` in `span`? Or that would be to much work for jQuery to handle (find, removed wrapped before, wrap new matches)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ScKJC/3/) is something I came up with using [this](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html) plugin. It is as simple as:

```
$('#searchable').highlight(filter);
```

EDIT: Updated link, fixed some issues.

Comment: @NewUser no problem. You can find the js file for the plugin [here](https://raw.github.com/bartaz/sandbox.js/master/jquery.highlight.js), so you don't have to include that ugly lump of code.

Comment: Not working on IE-2.0 (error: unknow tag `<script>`)... just kidding :)

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to define `escapreRegExp` function to ensure your search string is not a regex pattern:

```
function escapeRegExp(str) {
  return str.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&");
}
```

Then you need to modify your script as follows:

```
$(SearchableElements).each(function(){
  this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace(
    /<span\s[^>]*?class=['"]highlight['"].*?>(.*?)<\/span>/g, "$1");
  if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
  ... 
  } else {
    var re = new RegExp("(" + escapeRegExp(filter) + ")(?![^<]*>)", "gi");
    this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace(re, 
       "<span class='highlight' style='background-color: #FFFF00'>$1</span>");
    ...
```

Test this code **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/MHDXN/)**.

Comment: Can you please add some comment to explain the login/actions behind it?

Comment: Work great on Chrome & FF. Uncomfortably, IE8 is falling over.

Comment: What login you are talking about? My code is pure JavaScript that should work on IE8 as well.

Comment: Sorr, I meant logic*. It does work in IE8, but the browser performance is pure so after couple of keyup events it is falling over.